# Command php artisan migrate not defined - Laravel deployment

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, production, migrate

I'm trying to **deploy** a locally working Laravel 4 project on a Strato server.

Locally I can execute the command php artisan migrate, but when I'm trying to execute this command on the server using PuTTY command line, it throws the following exception:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Command "migrate" is not defined.

These have been my deployment steps:

1. Install **basic laravel application** locally, using composer (path variable)
2. **Upload** all files to the server. Now the warning, that a database column couldn't be found is visible. So I want to migrate the database.
3. Run the command php artisan **migrate**

When I run the command **php artisan list** there are a few methods listed like tail and workbench, but not the commands that I need.

PHP 5.5 and MCrypt are installed on the server.

Do I have to extend the artisan installation?

Update:
The problem seems to be the following:

> Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not
>   the cgi-fcgi SAPI

Futhermore there is this warning:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
>   composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to
>   update them.

Running update doesn't work, because it tries to run a mising artisan argument.

Comment: Try `composer update` then `php artisan dump-autoload` then try again.

Comment: During running `php composer.phar update` the next exception is thrown: In my compose.json script there's a "pre-update-cmd" `php artisan clear-compiled`. The server doesn't know this artisan command as well. It seems that I don't have access to all artisan commands.

Comment: For followers: **don't execute** the command `php composer.phar update` on production environment! (says laravel doc). But that hasn't caused my problem. The execution was canceled like said before.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that my webhoster uses the cgi-fcgi SAPI version by default, but **I will need CLI** to get all options for artisan. I've seen somebody using php-cli, but that doesn't work for me. How can I enable/access the php-cli command execution?